# Login Attempt in ASp.net Identity MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In Simple Membership Provider we could do something like below to track number of invalid attempt of login .

```
WebSecurity.IsAccountLockedOut(userName, allowedPasswordAttempts, intervalInSeconds)
```

This is not Supported in ASP NET Identity (http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

**I am trying to Display ReCaptcha on Invalid Login Attempt after around 5 login attempt.  I cannot find any example around from ASP NET Identity MVC 5. any help?**

Answer (score 1):

Try changing GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method inside ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs to this:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        T user = await _userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            if (((int) HttpContext.Current.Session["Tries"]) >= 5)
            {
                context.SetError("maximum_tries", "You tried too many times");
                return;
            }
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Tries"] = ((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["Tries"]) + 1;
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
            context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, GenerareProperties(user));
        context.Validated(ticket);

        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);

        HttpContext.Current.Session["Tries"] = 0;
    }
```

Simply I used session to track how many times user wrote invalid password. If the session value equals to 5 then we displaying another message.

Comment: i don;t even see this file ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs in the MVC5 template. i this a new file i need to create?

Comment: @JustinHomes Can you show me your Startup.Auth.cs (in App_Start folder) and AccountController.cs?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to access HttpContext.Current.Session in this function, is there something extra you need to do to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of ASP.NET Identity: 2.0.0-beta1 has been recently revealed and two new classes named UserManager and UserStore used by the ASP.NET Identity.

You can get the introduction of ASP.NET Identity from the following link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-Asp-Net-identity-in-visual-studio-2013/

If you want to apply the register and login through the use of ASP.NET Identiy, the following links are helpful:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-mvc-using-Asp-Net-identity-2-0-0-beta1/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-new-Asp-Net-identity-2-0-0-in-Asp-Net-applicati/